# Size 29×1.9/2.125 inner tube into my 700×40

Tags: tire, rims, compatibility, size

I just put a size 29×1.9 inner tube into my 700x40 hybrid tyre. Is it safe to use? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

2.125 is about a 54. That's enough mismatch that over long term use you could see the thing where the surface of the tube picks up a crinkled texture and it could maybe split and fail under pressure, especially if you're running high pressure, I.e. 55+ PSI. For this reason it's not really optimal, but it's a long term issue (probably years) if anything ever did happen.

Comment: I was only planning to use it for 2 months maximum till i get new tubes, but i was worried it might explode or do something to the outer tyre. Thank you for your help.